Installation watchface from smartphone to watch
Good day to all.
I'm a beginner in Android and Wear OS.
Therefore, I ask for advice from experienced people.
I created a watchface. I created a companion app for smartphone.
Everything works great.
But so far there is no way to install a watchface on the watch from the companion application.
There are applications that do this via Wi-Fi connection.
But, is it possible, in principle, to install a watchface on a watch from a companion application via Bluetooth pairing?
I would be grateful for advice on what direction to look in.
I tried to experiment with sending apk from phone to watch via Bluetooth and with remoteActivityHelper. So far no success.
I read a lot of advice, but they are outdated and did not help.
